# Why are determinants computed the way they are?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I understand the formula on how to compute determinants and I understand how we get to the $(a\times d)-(c\times b)$.

> My question is why do we multiply the way we multiply? Is there any reason or proof?

Comment: There are some properties (one of them being the multi-linearity) determining the determinant. But I do not remember the full set of the properties.

Comment: [@Peter is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant): the determinant is the only function of square matrices, mutlilinear and antisymmetric in all columns, satisfying $\det I=1$.

Comment: If your question really is "why do we multiply the way we multiply?", then I do not think you "understand how we get to the (a•d)-(c•b)". Because that understanding _will tell you why_.

Comment: What you're asking is not perfectly clear. Are you asking for a proof of $det(A \cdot B)=detA \cdot detB$ for $A,B\in M_{n \times n}$? Or perhaps why a determinant of a matrix $A \in M_{n \times n}$ multiplied with a scalar $c$ is the same as the determinant of the matrix obtained by multiplying a row of $A$ with $c$?

Comment: I wonder if your real question is why the determinant is interesting. To be fair, [some other things are too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanant).

Comment: Solve a general $2 \times 2$ linear system of equations on paper and the determinant will appear. That's the simplest way to discover the determinant, and it's unavoidable. We would stumble over the determinant even if we weren't looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Gaussian elimination,

$$\begin{cases}ax+by=e,\\cx+dy=f\end{cases}$$

then

$$\begin{cases}ax+by=e,\\0x+\left(d-b\dfrac ca\right)y=f-e\dfrac ca\end{cases}.$$

The second equation can also be written

$$(ad-bc)y=(af-ec).$$

Does this ring a bell ?

---

More deeply, the expression of a determinant is the simplest algebraic expression that cancels out when the rows or columns of the matrix are linearly dependent (it is a multilinear antisymmetric polynomial), and it is no surprise that it appears in the resolution of linear systems of equations.